# How to implement username/password auth with express ntlm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-ntlm

I am trying to implement username and password auth with Express-ntlm.I have added below code as middleware

```
app.use( ntlm({
domain: '<domainname>',
domaincontroller: '<ldap url>',
}));
```

I am not providing any user name password in the request and its automatically adding ntlm header in the request with my loggedin user details. I am getting `{Authenticated:true}` along with my username and system name in `request.ntlm`. 
How can I provide different username/password in this and authenticate?
Also will this work if I login from linux/mac system?

Comment: Are you reaching this endpoint with a browser? Or Postman?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a supported browser (e.g. IE) NTLM will automatically log the user in using the current session in Windows. `express-ntlm` will just receive this information and exposes it to the application.

If you want to use other credentials you have to log in using a different user in Windows or use a browser that will show you a prompt for username and password if it gets an NTLM challenge. If I remember correctly Chrome will do it like this.

I never tried it using macOS/Linux, but I'm sure most browser will just provide you a username/password prompt.

Comment: I agreed with you answer but that prompt only capture the username but not password. can you please suggest me how to get entered password in backend.

Comment: @KARTHIKEYAN.A That's not how the protocol works. If you need the user's password you need a custom login

Comment: okay, thanks, then will write my custom logic.